# UINavigationController+UITableView: Design pattern: perform three actions

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UINavigationController and a UITableView.

I want the user to be able to:

1. Add a new row.
2. Move back to the previous UIViewController.
   These two actions are supported by the following design pattern:

   ```
   [[Back]    Title   [+]]
   ```

However if I also want the user to be able to edit the list, how then do I do this? There is no position for the Edit button. Unless I replace the [+] symbol with an Edit button:

```
[[Back]    Title   [Edit]]
```

When the edit button is clicked this becomes:

```
[Done]  Title    [+]
--------------------
(-) Row name     (=)
(-) Row name 2   (=)
```

Is this a valid solution?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps take an example from the built-in Contacts app?  You could add a footer row to your sections that has the plus icon and will add a new row when tapped:

```
[Back]  Title [Edit/Done]
(-) Row 1     (=)
(-) Row 2     (=)
(+) Add a row
```